# Which category does the percent symbol fall into?

Tags: functions

I have looked around, for an answer, please pardon me if you find one that I have missed. My question is whether the %(divide x by 100) symbol is an operator or function and if neither, which category it falls into in mathematics terms.

Comment: I've known some teachers that treated it as a unit of measure.  To a degree, I agree with this in the abstract sense of a unit of measure: it indicates that x% is taken to mean the ratio $x:100$.

Comment: It's somewhat like a unit of measure, when we write "7m" we really mean 7 times a meter. Same goes for %, except one can expand % into $^{1}/_{100}$

Comment: The symbol "%" stands for exactly "divided by 100" and nothing more. It is purely a mathematical shorthand. So 7% is exactly 0.07 and nothing more. $x= (100x)/100=(100x)%. I can't answer your question about "operator" versus "function" until you define the term "operator" in this context. I would say provisionally it is a unary operator, much as the square root symbol is.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'll take it as a unary operator since it fits the description well.

Comment: Note that operators **are** functions. So the implication that this falls into exactly one of these categories is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by MPW in comments:

> The symbol "%" stands for exactly "divided by 100" and nothing more. It is purely a mathematical shorthand. So 7% is exactly 0.07 and nothing more. $x= (100x)/100=(100x)\%$.
>
> Note that operators **are** functions. So the implication that this falls into exactly one of these categories is mistaken. I would say provisionally $\%$ is a unary operator, much as the square root symbol is.